# How to create RECORD in an object2 when Record is created in object1 (trigger/ apex class)?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to autopopulate record for Object2 when record is created in object1. I am writing a trigger adapted from https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176618&language=en_US
The trigger throws no error, but no Transaction Record is created when Journal record is created. Journal has lookup relation with Transaction object & all required fields for both object has been included. What am i missing?

```
trigger Post8 on Journal__c (AFTER insert) {

List <Transaction__c> vehToInsert = new List <Transaction__c>(); 
for (Journal__c o : Trigger.new) {
    Transaction__c v = new Transaction__c (); 
    v.Description__c = o.Description__c; 
    v.Reference__c = o.Reference__c; 
    vehToInsert.add(v);
}try {
    insert vehToInsert; 
} catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
    system.debug (e);
}}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: No error & no trigger fire

Comment: Put a "system.debug();" statement right at the top of your trigger to see if the trigger is firing or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
trigger Post8 on Journal__c (after insert){

List <Transaction__c> vehToInsert = new List <Transaction__c>();

    for(Journal__c o : trigger.new){
        Transaction__c v = new Transaction__c(Description__c = o.Description__c,
                            Reference__c=o.Reference__c);
        vehToInsert.add(v);
    }
    try {
        insert vehToInsert; 
    } 
    catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
        system.debug (e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this too. no Transaction is created

Comment: try putting debugs in between and then let us know where the code broke.Do check if your trigger is getting fired or not?

Comment: Is your trigger active?

Comment: Yes, the trigger is active, & i find no error anywhere. 
So, as the trigger is not working, I have developed a Action by process builder, & the functionality achieved.

Comment: That's good.But i am really interested in knowing why your trigger is not getting fired.Could you please try changing your event to Before Insert?